Next Auth v5, the Session data not updated after signing in. Middleware file not working as expected
I am new to NextAuth v5 and have been facing a lot of bugs.
1: After the user signed in, the session data is never updated unless I refresh the page (I had to force refresh using setTimeout)
2: I want to redirect signed-in users from /sign-in and /sign-up route via Middleware but it's not working as expected.
I have been following the docs, asking the AI bot and watching youtube tutorials but still cannot fix this.
auth.js


const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    Credentials({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {
        
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (credentials === null) return null;
        const { username, password } = credentials;

        try {
          await connectDB();
          const user= await User.findOne({username});
          
          if (!user) {
            throw new Error("User not found");
          }
          const passwordMatch= await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
          if (!passwordMatch) {
            throw new Error("Email or Password is not correct");
          }

          return { id: user._id, fullname: user.fullname, username: user.username, profile: user.profilepic };
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          return null;
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.AUTH_SECRET,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/sign-in",
  },
  session:{
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user.id;
        token.fullname = user.fullname;
        token.username = user.username;
        token.profile = user.profile;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user.id = token.id;
      session.user.fullname = token.fullname;
      session.user.username = token.username;
      session.user.profile = token.profile;
      return session;
    },
    
  },
 
};

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut,update } = NextAuth(authOptions);



helper.js
'use server'
import { signIn,signOut } from '@/auth'

export async function doCredentialLogin(inputs) {
  try {
    const res= await signIn('credentials', {
      redirect: false,
      username: inputs.username,
      password: inputs.password
    });
    return res;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

export async function doLogout() {
  await signOut({ redirectTo: "/sign-in" });

}

useSignup.jsx
const useSignUp = () => {
    const [loading,setLoading]=useState(false)
    const router = useRouter()

    const signup=async({fullname,username,password,confirmPassword})=>{
        const sucess=handleInputErrors({fullname,username,password,confirmPassword});
        if(!sucess) return;
        setLoading(true)
        try {
            const res=await fetch('/api/sign-up',{
                method:'POST',
                headers:{
                    'Content-Type':'application/json'
                },
                body:JSON.stringify({fullname,username,password,confirmPassword})
            })
            if(res.status===201)
                {
                const signInRes=await doCredentialLogin({username,password})
                if(signInRes.error) throw new Error("An unexpected error occurred")
                toast.success("Account created successfully!")
                router.push('/')
                setTimeout(() => {
                    window.location.reload(); 
                  }, 600);  
            
                }
            else{
                const data=await res.json()
                throw new Error(data.error)
            }
            
        } catch (error) {
            toast.error(error.message)       
        }
        finally{
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }
    return {signup,loading}
}

export default useSignUp;

/sign-in
const { update } = useSession();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setLoading(true);
  
    try {
      const res = await doCredentialLogin(inputs);
  
      if (res.error) {
        console.error(res.error);
        toast.error("Invalid credentials");
      } else {
        await update();
        router.push('/');  // Navigate to the home page
      setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.reload();  // Force page reload
      }, 500);  // Adjust the timeout as needed

      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('login', error);
      toast.error("An unexpected error occurred");
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

middleware.ts
import { auth } from "@/auth"; 
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default auth((req) => {
  if (!req.auth) {
    const url = req.url.replace(req.nextUrl.pathname, "/");
    return NextResponse.redirect(url);
  }
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/sign-in", "/sign-up"],
};

